# How to pass the result of an event to a template on meteor

Tags: meteor, meteor-helper

I am new to meteor and i am wondering how am i able to pass the result of a query that is the result of a click event of a template to another template that will show up after click event.

```
Template.projectList.events({

    "click .list-group-item": function(){
        //Session.set("projectSelected", true);
        Session.set("projectSelected", this._id)
    }
});

<template name="projectDetail">
<div class="project">
    <h4 class="project-title">
        <span>{{name}}</span>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash pull-right del"></i>
        <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus pull-right add"></i>
    </h4>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="project-description">
        <label>Project description:</label>
        <p>
        {{remarks}}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</template>
```

I made some revision and did something similar to that 1st suggestion. But i did not put the entire query result to the session. Instead i place the selected id and made the helper query the details of the project. But by doing so, still to no avail of the desired result.

```
Template.projectDetail.helpers({

    detail: function(){

        if(Session.get("projectSelected")){
            var proj = Project.find({_id: Session.get("projectSelected")}).fetch();
        }

        return proj;
    }

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use helpers for that. For example, assuming project is the result you want to pass to projectDetail template:

```
Template.projectList.events({    
    "click .list-group-item": function(){
        Session.set("projectSelected", true);    
        var project = Project.find({_id: this._id}).fetch();
        // Store project in Session
        Session.set("aProject", project);
    }
});
Template.projectDetail.helpers({
    project: function () {
        // Get the project back from Session
        var project = Session.get("aProject");
        return project;
    }
});
```

So now, in your projectDetail template, {{project}} will depend on the result of the query from the click event.

Comment: Hi i did as you suggested buy to no avail.. how do i capture that result now to my template?

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean by 'capture the result to template'? Also what the query result actually contains could help provide a more specific answer.

Comment: Its ok now, i tried your suggestion and also tried the workaround i did with a similar idea to your suggestion. our idea was actually correct. the problem is on the template. I used {{#with project}} spacebar as i believe its the correct one to use, but its not getting the data. I used {{#each}} and now its getting the returned data. Can you explain to me the proper usage of {{#with}}

Comment: `each` iterates over an array, while `with` is more similar to `import` in languages like java or C++. Here's a link with a good explanation: [link](http://meteorcapture.com/spacebars/#with)